# select all rows where a condition over columns is true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have this df :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({times:[1,2,3],'1' : [True,False,True], '2':[False,False,True]})
```

I want to return rows where columns '1' OR '2' are true :

```
expected_df : 
times '1'   '2'
1      True  False
3      True  True
```

In my real example I have many more columns so I'm looking for a solution using the list of the df's columns like :
`df.loc[df[myColumns]==True]`

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of columns:

```
df.loc[df[myColumns].all(1)]
```

Comment: It only returns where all the columns are True. I want to return if one or more a True

Comment: @Pi-R change `all(1)` to `any(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
columns = [...]
mask = df[columns[0]] == true
for col_name in columns[1:]:
    mask = mask | df[col_name] == true
my_df = df[mask]
```

Comment: I should precise that, in my real example I only have the list of columns which is pretty big and can change times to times

Comment: This is the same as `df[df['1'] & df['2']]`

Comment: u can run a mask as a loop

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.apply(sum, axis=1)>0]
```

This could work since rows with at least 1 True will have a value > 0 and you won't have to list out all column names if there are several columns.